# Issue with changing date format inline with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am pulling a date from a database and it is in the format 2017-12-07.  That is how I was displaying the date, however, I would like to display is like Dec 7, 17.

What I tried.

```
echo "<td>" . date_format($row['returndate'],'M d, y') . "</td>";
```

My results end up empty.  I have successfully changed the date format with in the MYSQLI line, however, I was wanting to do it with PHP.

UPDATE

I apologize, it seems I over looked something simple.  Below fixed it.

```
date('M d, y', strtotime($row['returndate']))
```

I guess you have to do strtotime before date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
echo "<td>" . date('M d, y', strtotime($row['returndate'])) . "</td>";
```

**Output**

```
Dec 07, 17
```

Comment: This is how I ended up fixing it.  I guess I was typing my edit while you answered.  Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

`date_format` requires an `DateTime` object. In your case, you can simply use (without class `DateTime`):

```
print date('M d, y', strtotime('2017-12-07'));
Dec 07, 17
```

Or if you would like to use `DateTime` exactly, you can try:

```
php > $d = new DateTime('2017-12-07');
php > print $d->format('M d, y');
Dec 07, 17
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the php `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime($row['returndate']);
echo $date->format('M d, y');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the date , 
first create date object and then pass it  date_format
For eg:

```
$date = date_create($row['returndate']);
echo "<td>" . date_format($date,'M d, y') . "</td>";
```

Output

```
Dec 07, 17
```